# Как использовать маски слоев (layermask) и для чего пишут 1 << layer?

Tags: c#, unity3d, битовые-операции

Доброго времени суток!

Я разбираюсь в работе *Unity*, смотрю уроки, некоторые скрипты и иногда встречаю конструкцию вида `1 << layer`, где `layer` является целым числом. Чаще это встречаю в методах, связанных с физикой, например `Raycast`:

```
public int groundLayer = 5; 

void SomeMethod() {
    // do smth...
    if (Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0f, 1 << groundLayer).Length > 0) { 
        ...
    }
    // do smth...
}
```

И не только с физикой:

```
LayerMask Collisionmask;
int layer = 5;

void SomeMethod() {
    // do smth...
    if ((Collisionmask.value & (1 << layer)) == 0) {
        ...
    }
    // do smth...
}
```

Читал, что это какие-то маски. Они указывают на слои. Но мне не понятно, что это за маски, как их использовать, причем тут вообще слои? Что же такое `1 << layer`, например?

Может кто-нибудь объяснить подробно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Запаситесь попкорном и колой (пирожками и чаем). Это будет долго, но познавательно. ))

## Что это и к чему?

В *Unity*, как мы все (или не только лишь все) знаем, имеются слои (layers).  Освежить память о том, что это (а если не знаете, то прочитать и ознакомиться) можно в **[документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Layers.html)**. Используются они по-разному. К примеру в `2D` с их помощью можно обозначить и отделить задний/средний/передний план. Что-то будет сзади, что-то спереди. В более сложных играх слоёв может быть больше и объекты можно группировать по этим слоям. Например, можно сделать слой для `NPC` и выделить из него  слой для враждебных *NPC* - `Enemies` и прочие.

В общем случае манипуляции с `layerMask` (маской) позволяют выяснить, находится ли проверяемый объект (GameObject) в указанном слое или нет (неважно, что это за объект и каким образом он проверяется). В зависимости от результата проверки производить задуманные действия.

Рассмотрим, к примеру, `Raycast`. Если обратимся к **[документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)**, то можно увидеть, что метод выглядит так:

```
public static RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector2 origin, Vector2 direction, float distance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity);
```

Один из параметров: `int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers`. Работает он так: из некой точки в каком-то направлении выпускается луч (допустим это такая магия на расстоянии), этот луч падает на какую-то преграду (объект) и, например, если этот объект находится в слое `Enemies` - ушмякать его. О примере `(Collisionmask.value & (1 << layer)) == 0` поговорим ниже. Но суть у него аналогичная: определить принадлежность за счет маски > сделать что-то в зависимости от...

Надеюсь с сутью понятно, пойдем далее.

## Как это работает.

Количество слоев в *Unity*: 32. Нумеруются они с 0 до 31.

[image: i1]

`LayerMask` (маска) - представляется в виде 32-битного целого числа:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Я отделил каждые 4 бита для лучшей читабельности.

Маска использует свои 32 бита для представления различных **[флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))** (состояние объекта, например: 1 - включен, 0 - выключен). В данном конкретном случае каждый флаг (бит) представляет собой конкретный слой. Возьмем для разбора первые 8 слоев и запишем двоичное представление каждого слоя (**Первый бит (младший) находится с правой стороны**).

```
слой №    Двоичное    Десятичное
----------------------------------
Layer 0 = 0000 0001 = 1
Layer 1 = 0000 0010 = 2
Layer 2 = 0000 0100 = 4
Layer 3 = 0000 1000 = 8
Layer 4 = 0001 0000 = 16
Layer 5 = 0010 0000 = 32
Layer 6 = 0100 0000 = 64
Layer 7 = 1000 0000 = 128
```

Вот что представляют из себя слои в двоичном представлении. Как видим, конкретный слой определяется одним конкретным битом.

Теперь пробуем разбираться на примере `if ((Collisionmask.value & (1 << layer)) == 0)`.

Мы видим переменную `layer`, которая является целым числом. Эта переменная — **номер слоя** (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...), **НЕ** десятичное и **НЕ** двоичное представление. `Collisionmask` в инспекторе представляет собой выпадающий список со слоями:

[image: i2]

А `Collisionmask.value` в свою очередь является **двоичным представлением** комбинации выбранных слоёв (так как выбрать можем не один а несколько слоев). Для понимания: например, если мы хотим создать маску для слоя #2 и #5, то двоичное представление будет такое:

```
0010 0100  // #2,#5
```

или например слои #1, #2, #5, #6 будут представлять из себя:

```
0110 0110 // #1,#2,#5,#6
```

**Что мы хотим?** Мы хотим узнать, входит ли в эту маску проверяемый нами слой `layer`? И в зависимости от этого что-то сделать. В примере выше мы хотим зайти в условие и что-то сделать, если наш объект, находящийся в слое 5, **не** входит в указанную маску.

Допустим `LayerMask = 0110 0110; // #1,#2,#5,#6`, а номер нашего слоя `int layer = 5;`

Нужно слой 5 привести к его двоичному представлению, соответствующее в слоях. Посмотрим в табличку вверху. Слой 5 имеет десятичное представление равное 32. Оно, в свою очередь, в двоичном представлением является 0010 0000. 
Оно получается за счет применения побитого оператора сдвига влево `<<` относительно самого младшего бита (0000 0001) именно на 5 значений (фантастика!). Сдвигаем единичку 5 раз влево:

[image: i3]

Как видим получилось число 0010 0000 и оно действительно входит в нашу маску `0110 0110`, потому что маска содержит единичку в позиции номер 6 справа, и слой 5 имеет единичку на такой же позиции. Если не верите на слово, то проверить легко: надо произвести побитовое умножение (побитовое И "&") между маской и проверяемым значением. Это, кстати, и делается в строке `Collisionmask.value & (1 << layer)`

```
0110 0110 // #1,#2,#5,#6
& (and)
0010 0000 // #5
---------
0010 0000
```

Видим, что входит в маску. Если бы не входил, то побитовое умножение дало бы результат 0. Как пример доказательства, можем проверить входит ли слой 7 в данную маску или нет. Сдвигаем младший бит на 7 позиций влево:

[image: i3.2]

Получаем 1000 0000. Проверяем

```
0110 0110 // #1,#2,#5,#6
& (and)
1000 0000 // #7
---------
0000 0000
```

Видим 0. Не входит. И раз оно не входит, значит срабатывает наше условие сверху:

```
if ((Collisionmask.value & (1 << layer)) == 0) => if (0 == 0)  => true
```

значит мы заходим в условие и делаем что нам нужно. Это то, что мы и искали.

---

#### Дополнение 1

Помимо проверки конкретного слоя на вхождение в маску, можно проверять, наоборот, все слои, **кроме** указанного. Нужно только использовать, так скажем, оператор инверсии (~). 
Он меняет в битовом представлении операнда 0 на 1, а 1 - на 0. Таким образом ~00000010 будет равен 11111101, что будет тестировать каждый слой, кроме #2. 
Если хотите исключить несколько слоев, то нужно будет скомбинировать маски через оператор "ИЛИ":

```
int layer1 = 3;
int layer2 = 5;
int layermask = ~((1 << layer1) | (1 << layer2)) // НЕПРАВИЛЬНО: ~(1 << layer1) | ~(1 << layer2)
```

---

#### Дополнение 2

На самом деле не всегда нужно писать `1 << что-то`. Например в `Raycast` можно в параметр передать `Collisionmask.value`, где  `Collisionmask` имеет тип **[LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html)**, а он, в свою очередь, в инспекторе выглядит как выпадающий список (см. изображение №2). Очень удобно.

Также не стоит хардкодить числами, т.е. не писать `1 << 7` или `1 << 5`, т.к. можно забыть, что это за 5 и 7. Для того, чтоб узнать нужное число слоя, можно пользоваться **[LayerMask.NameToLayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html)**, пример:

```
int npcLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("NPCLayer");   
int npcMask = 1 << npcLayer;
```

и тоже самое при "групповых" масках:

```
int npcGoodLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("NPCGood");
int friendsLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Friends");
int npcGoodMask = 1 << npcGoodLayer;
int friendsMask = 1 << friendsLayer;
int finalmask = npcGoodMask | friendsMask; // Or, (1 << npcGoodLayer) | (1 << friendsLayer)
```

#### Дополнение 3

На самом деле такая конструкция `1 << ...` встречается не только в Юнити. Это известная практика вообще в программировании. К примеру есть у какого-либо производителя продукт, приложение и он предоставляет API для других программистов.

> API - набор готовых классов, процедур, функций, структур и констант, предоставляемых приложением (библиотекой, сервисом) или операционной системой для использования во внешних программных продуктах. Используется программистами при написании всевозможных приложений. (c) Википедия

У API могут быть ограничения на доступ различного рода. Программист указывает маску, к чему он хочет получить доступ, а на сервере приложения проверяется это и в случае несовпадения по маске - выдает предупреждение или еще что-либо.
Самый простой пример Вконтакте и его **[права доступа для API](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)**

[image: i4]

Там указано десятичное представление, но сути не меняет.

Comment: Ого, ничего себе! Фундаментальный труд!

Comment: @VladD благодарю. надеюсь хоть что-то понятно написал.

Comment: Здорово, особенно то, что все на реальном примере, так не возникает вопросов зачем все это нужно =) Сам недавно этот прием использовал чтобы компактно хранить выбранные дни недели в триггерах

Comment: разве что стоит добавить, что подобный прием, несмотря на кажущуюся сложность, работает существенно быстрее кучи `IF`-ов или `switch .. case`

Comment: @rdorn я уж и не знаю куда это вписать-то можно :-D  ..... но вы можете внести правку %)

Comment: @rdom, если говорить про быстрее, маски нужно кешировать в переменных рядом с номером слоя. Нечего биты каждый раз двигать)