# Флаги сообщений vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Может у кого уже был опыт с работой в вк api и longpolling. Получаю событие о новом сообщение, мне нужно понять, что событие было отправлено мной или другим юзером, для этого как я понял, нужно использовать флаги сообщений. К примеру если я оптправляю текстовое сообщение и его не прочитали еще, то мне приходит флаг 35. Но как мне понять из чего именно получилось такое значение, не пойму как применить суммирование?

С флагом 35, разобрался, это 32+2+1, но почему когда я отправляю сообщение кому-то мне приходит - 35, хотя 32, это если сообщение отправлено другом? Если кто-то отправляет сообщение мне, то флаг у него будет 33.

https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно разбираться с суммированием, нужно всего лишь проверить на наличие нужного флага в присылаемой маске. Это проверяется посредством побитового оператора. В данном случае это будет побитовое умножение (побитовое И "&") между  полученной маской и проверяемым значением.

Например пришло значение 35. Нужно проверить, а было ли сообщение исходящим? Какое значение для проверки? Оно равно 2. Вот и смотрим:

```js
var result = !!(35 & 2);
console.log(result);
```

Видим результат: true.

Можем посмотреть результат на маске 33:

```js
var result = !!(33 & 2);
console.log(result);
```

Результат: false

Собственно и всё. Таким образом и узнается входит ли нужный флаг из таблицы в  присылаемую с сервера маску или нет.

Можете частично информацию почерпнуть **[Отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603545/191482)**

---

Если утрировать то примеры выше получаются как-то так:

с маской 35 и флагом 2:

```
100011 // 35
&
000010 // 2
------
000010 // true
```

с маской 33 и флагом 2:

```
100001 // 33
&
000010 // 2
------
000000 // false
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!