# Побитовые операции - как получить значение определенного бита?

Tags: c, delphi, битовые-операции

Здравствуйте.
Как получить значение определенного бита в байте?
Допустим мы имеем байт с битами вида:
00110101

Как можно получить значение 4 или 5 бита?
Пример можно показать на любом языке, предпочтительнее C или Delphi.

Comment: В Си `if (b & (1 << 4)) { // бит №4 (у первого бита номер 0) установлен ...`

Comment: А вы не могли бы поподробнее расписать что значит данная конструкция? Насколько я понял b это у нас и есть байт.
А 1 << 4 это мы как бы сдвигаемся на 4 бит?

Comment: Точно. b это ваш байт, а (1 << 4) битовая маска (4-й бит установлен, остальные 0 (`<<` это операция побитового сдвига влево)) и `&` это битовая операция `AND`

Comment: Вообщем вашу конструкцию можно объяснить примерно как:
Возьмем байт и сделаем что то с его битами, затем берем байт 4 и ставим его значение в 1

Comment: А читать как? Допустим я хочу чекнуть, является ли 5 бит 1.

Comment: Тогда маска `(1 << 5)` и та же операция AND (вы вообще, хоть что-то про Си читали?)

Comment: @avp, просто я все время хайлевел кодил, о битах вообще речи не было, так получилось.
А сейчас под NES захотел кодить :)

Comment: @avp: Неужели у вас нигде нету большого ответа об этом? Вот не поверю.

Comment: Вот это `Возьмем байт и сделаем что то с его битами` верно, а вот это `затем берем байт 4 и ставим его значение в 1` нет. Что-то делаем, означает -- делаем побитовую операцию AND над всеми битами байта и маской в которой **бит 4 установлен в 1**. Если результат 0 -- бит 4 в байте **сброшен** (иначе установлен)

Comment: @avp, спасибо. Напишите развернутый ответ, и я помечу его как лучший

Comment: @VladD, думаю нет. Обычно такую тривиальщину пишу в комментариях (если  человек поймет, что ему нужно глубже разобраться пусть читает книжки)

Comment: @avp: Тогда, возможно, имеет смысл эту тривиальщину один раз описать понятным новичкам языком, и каждый раз просто давать ссылку :)

Comment: @VladD, может кто и напишет (мне лень -) Да и как потом найти этот ответ? (вообще же, прямо на этой странице есть ссылки на аналогичные вопросы-ответы -- например, вот ответ Бармалея http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/281666/232)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603545/176064

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если вас интересует буквальное значение бита (т.е. `0` или `1`), то в языке С значение `i`-того бита числа `n` можно получить как

```
(n >> i) & 1u
```

Если вас интересует взвешенное значение бита (т.е. `0` или `8` для бита номер 3), то в языке С значение `i`-того бита числа `n` можно получить как

```
n & (1u << i)
```

(Подразумевается нумерация с нуля от младших битов к старшим.)

Answer (score 9):

Функция на Delphi для проверки, установлен ли конкретный бит в 32-х битном числе:

```
function IsBitSet(const AValue: Cardinal; const ABit: Byte): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (AValue and (1 shl ABit)) <> 0;
end;
```

Операция `(1 shl ABit)` (порязрядный сдвиг значения целого числа влево, на указанное число бит) генерирует число, в котором установлен в 1 только один бит именно в той позиции которая нас интересует. Это число называется *маской*.

Далее, применяется логическая операция `AND` к входному значению и маске, в результате чего получается ещё одно число, которое либо равно 0 (все биты установлены в 0), либо равно маске, т.е. установлен только один бит. Соответственно, сравнив результат с нулём можно сделать вывод о том, установлен искомый бит или нет.

Картинка, поясняющая работу логической операции `AND`:

[image: AND]

Результирующий бит считается установленным только **если у обоих** операндов соответствующий бит так же установлен.

В вашем примере, при поиске 4-го бита, будет производится вот такое сложение:

```
00110101 - входное значение
00001000 - маска
--------
00000000 - результат = 0, т.е 4-й бит не установлен
```