# Как разбить число на биты и записать его в массив в си?

Tags: c, системы-счисления

есть число, к примеру 100000 или 186a0 в hex. Это двоичное число состоящие из 17 знаков, а значит поместится в 3 байтовый массив. Вопрос в том, как это число правильно распихвать по этим 3 байтам массива. Я пробова переводить число в hex через sprintf, разбивал получившуюсь строку на подстроки по 2 элемента и с помощью atoi присваивал переведенное в число значение этих под строк в байты массива. Но это неправильный подход. Это нужно, для того, чтоб отправить значение по проторколу WS и его можно было расшифровать с помощью поитовых операций. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642585/276430

Comment: Зачем вам запихивать его в 3 байта? Как вы узнаете, сколько байтов занимает пришедшее число? Отправляйте всегда 4.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, в протоколе WS  количество байт, в котором отправляется длина тела сообщения зависит от (тавтаогия) длины тела сообщения. Если длина меньше 65535 байт то число умещается в 2 байта, если больше, то отправляется 8 байт, так как в примере число 100000 оно помещается в 3 байта, остальные 5 перед ним заменяются нулями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

с помощью поразрядных операций 
например, извлечь самый младший разряд можно с помощью логического умножения

```
int i = 5;   // 101b
int s = 0x1; // 001b
bool bit = i & s;   // 101b & 0x1h = 101b & 001b = 001
```

затем сдвигаешь s на один разряд влево и    повторяешь  операцию - получишь следующий разряд:

```
s <<= 1;    // s = 001b << 1 = 010b
bit = i & s; // bit = 101b & 010b = 0
```

и так далее

ну помещаешь в цикл, итераций должно быть столько же ,   сколько и разрядов занимает число типа int:

```
int intSizeInBits = sizeof(int) << 3;
for(int i = intSizeInBits ; i > 0; i--)
```

ну разделить число на байты тоже очень просто - с помощью всё того же логического умножения:

```
int n = 254; // 11111110b;
int s = 0xff; // 11111111b
char byte = n & s;  // byte = 11111110b & 11111111b = 11111110b;
```

аналогичным образом извлекааешь остальные байты,   только теперь сдвигаешь число s на восемь разрядов:

```
s <<= 8;
```

Comment: мне нужно не извлеч число, а перевести шестнадцатиричное в двочиное, но так, чтоб кажде элемент двоичного числа занимал 1 байт

Comment: ааа,     так тебе просто надо разбить число на три байта ??

Comment: по сути да, срасшифровкой я уже разобрался

Comment: Не обязательно на 3, просто число 100занимает 3 байта в двочиной системе

Comment: ну отковырять байт от числа тоже несложно:  поправлю    ща ответ погоди

Comment: @DenverToha  да хоть на три хоть на пятьдесят   байтов разбивай,   этим способом можно как твоей душе угодно

Comment: @DenverToha ты понял алгоритм ??   сам дальше справишься ??

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли